# Python3 Loop: Time limit exceeded, Code Optimization

Tags: python-3.x, loops, optimization

I am trying to learn python by solving easy data structure problems on HackerRank.com. I tried to solve the [Left Rotation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem) challenge:

> A left rotation operation on an array of size  shifts each of the
> array's elements **1** unit to the left. Given an integer, ,
> rotate the array that many steps left and return the result.
>
> #### Example
>
> **= 2**
>  **= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]**
> After **2** rotations,  **= [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]**.

I suggested the following solution. It worked fine for 8 use cases, but gave a **time-out** error on the last two cases.

```py
def rotateLeft(d, arr):
    new = arr[0:]
    for _ in range(d):
        i, new = new[0], new[1:]
        new.append(i)
    return new
```

I'm not looking for some formula based **one-liner** solution. I know it would solve the problem at hand, but it won't help me understand how a simple loop based solution can be optimized.

I am looking for optimization rules, for this problem and in-general too.

Comment: How about you get rid of the loop and perform all the rotations in one go using slices? For instance, the example is `arr[2:] + arr[:2]`

Comment: `d` is a variable, given **slicing solution** only works if `d=4`.

Comment: Of course you make different slices for different values of `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Optimisation is possible, when you realise that `d` could be many times greater than the size of the list. In that case you would be wasting time rotating the list only to bring it several times back into its original order to finally reach the intended rotation.

So only perform `d % len(arr)` rotations.

A second optimisation is that you don't really have to perform the rotations one by one. You can do the `d % len(arr)` rotations in one go by slicing that many values from the left side (in one operation) and appending them to the right (in one operation). This way your code would not even have an explicit loop.

So in Python that is quite easy:

> `def rotateLeft(d, arr):`
>      `d %= len(arr)`
>      `return arr[d:] + arr[:d]`

If you want to do this by moving one value at a time, without slicing or list comprehension, then proceed as follows:

```
def rotateLeft(d, arr):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        result.append(arr[(i + d) % len(arr)])
    return result
```

...but this is not that efficient. Slicing is the Pythonic way to go.

Comment: I tried and limit rotations to `d % len(arr)` but last two cases are failing as mentioned.

Comment: You should also use the second optimisation.

Comment: it worked, but sir if may i ask u (as u seem very pro) that why this question got negative rating? it was legit question even you (who have this much rating) were unable to give correct "loop" answer at first. It seems no one here understand the question and keep vote down it unless its some "jarvis" level thing. My point was to optimize loop not to know alternate solutions, your first ans (`So only perform d % len(arr) rotations`) was very relevant but ofcourse it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the phrase *"I'm not looking for some formula based one-liner solution. I know it would solve the problem"* can urge some people to downvote for the following reasons: (1) many don't like artificial restrictions: we want to promote best practices in our answers, and this restriction forces people to answer with inferior solutions. This is not appreciated. (2) since you suggest to have working code, there really is not a problem any more. Finally, my initial answer didn't provide the full code, because we believe the asker should do an effort.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the provided solution is that it does a lot of memory allocations. Each time it calls `new.append(...)` the program needs to check  if it has enough memory allocated to add the provided element to the end of the list. In case there is not enough allocated memory, the program needs to allocate a new larger patch of memory and copy all the existing data over to the new location. This all takes a lot of time. In order to optimise it, consider a solution where you change the values of the list elements, instead of removing and adding elements to it. This will reduce the number of memory reallocations.

I am not going to provide a solution for the above, since I assume the whole purpose of this is to exercise the coding skills of the author.